# How can I have a empty number on play forms?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a form in my application that will insert information into the database, but its optional data, it can be nullable. I have this mapping:

```
  case class TransactionFormData(id:Long, transID:Long, operatorID:Long, cardID:Long, stationID:Long, startTime:String, endTime:String, lineNumber:Int, cardNumber:Long, transNumber:Long, ticketNumber:Int, amountEntered:Int, amountMeasured:Int, leaseID_dpID:Int, customerID:Int)
  val transForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> longNumber,
      "transID" -> longNumber,
      "operatorID" -> longNumber(min = 0),
      "cardID" -> longNumber,
      "stationID" -> longNumber,
      "startTime" -> nonEmptyText,
      "endTime" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lineNumber" -> number(min = 0),
      "cardNumber" -> longNumber(min = 0),
      "transNumber" -> longNumber(min = 0),
      "ticketNumber" -> OptionalMapping(number),
      "amountEntered" ->  number,
      "amountMeasured" -> number,
      "leaseID_dpID" -> number,
      "customerID" -> number
    )(TransactionFormData.apply)(TransactionFormData.unapply)
  )
```

from ticketNumber on down, the values can be kept empty, but when I try putting nothing in, the form helper returns an error and requires input, how can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `optional(number)` constraint:

```
"ticketNumber" -> optional(number),
"amountEntered" ->  optional(number),
"amountMeasured" -> optional(number),
"leaseID_dpID" -> optional(number),
"customerID" -> optional(number)
```

Just as `number` maps to `Int`, `optional(number)` maps to `Some[Int]`. The constraint allows the field to pass validation if no value is submitted in the form, assigning the field the value `None`. I appreciate however that this will then require you to change the signature of your case class constructor:

```
case class TransactionFormData(..., ticketNumber:Option[Int], ...)
```